# How to make c program as executable in windows 7

Tags: c, gcc

For a simple "hello world" application, I used the following commands in order to create an .exe file using the GCC Compiler:

> cpp hello.c > hello.i

(successful)

> gcc -S hello.i

(successful)

> as -o hello.o hello.s

(succesful)

When finally linking the files with the following command to obtain an .exe, I get an error:

```
C:\C_Experiments\test>ld -o test2.exe test2.o
test2.o:test2.c:(.text+  0  x  9): undefined reference to __main
test2.o:test2.c:(.text+0 x    15): undefined reference to printf
ld: test2.o: bad reloc address 0x0 in section `.pdata'
```

Comment: `gcc hello.c -o hello`

Comment: m still learning c programming , still trying to understand if my goal is to make a c program as executable how do it, i get what you sayin Joachim, just to make simple programe as executable, but on otherside http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html when i read in this article they provided few different steps for how to make c programe as executable in through GCC compiler, so the steps thave i have replicated such as assembly code creationb and machine code creation following with linkin all the files , so when is this process really required can you explains

Comment: check `gcc -v hello.c`

Answer (score 2):

You need to link with the runtime library which contains the startup function and all other standard functions.

Why not skip the preprocessor and assembler step, and go directly to object file? And also use `gcc` when linking which will add the needed extra libraries automatically? Or for simple single-source-file programs go directly to executable?

Either

```
$ gcc hello.c -c -o hello.o
$ gcc hello.o -o hello
```

Or

```
$ gcc hello.c -o hello
```

Comment: m still learning c programming , still trying to understand if my goal is to make a c program as executable how do it, i get what you sayin Joachim, just to make simple programe as executable, but on otherside http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html when i read in this article they provided few different steps for how to make c programe as executable in through GCC compiler, so the steps thave i have replicated such as assembly code creationb and machine code creation following with linkin all the files , so when is this process really required can you explains